How can one turn off Adobe Acrobat PDF reader in Google Chrome?
How can one turn off the Adobe Acrobat PDF reader extension in Google Chrome without having to disable the extension?

Why was this question on how to turn off Adobe Acrobat PDF reader in Google Chrome closed as not about computer hardware or software?

Click on the "..." icon on top right  (left of the share button) > Preferences > Open PDFs in Acrobat > Set to false.

